# How to crop the words in order as they appear in the text image

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a text image and I have found the contours for every word. Now I want to crop all the contours in the order they appear in the text. I have tried to sort the contours from left to right but did not succeed. How do I do this?

What I am getting in `result` is the word images in random order but I want them in the same order as in the image.

[image]

```
            Mat finalMat = mats[1];
            Mat mat2 = mats[0];
            Mat gray = new Mat(finalMat.rows(),finalMat.height(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(finalMat,gray,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            Mat mat = new Mat();

            Imgproc.dilate(mat2, mat, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(12, 5)));

            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

            Imgproc.findContours(mat,contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
            Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            Collections.sort(contours, new Comparator<MatOfPoint>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MatOfPoint o1, MatOfPoint o2) {
                Rect rect1 = Imgproc.boundingRect(o1);
                Rect rect2 = Imgproc.boundingRect(o2);
                int result = 0;
                double total = rect1.tl().y/rect2.tl().y;
                if (total>=0.9 && total<=1.4 ){
                    result = Double.compare(rect1.tl().x, rect2.tl().x);
                }
                return result;
            }
        });

          for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {

                if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx)) > 50 ){
                    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(contourIdx));
                    if (rect.height > 28){
                        Mat crop;
                        if((rect.y + rect.height+15)<gray.rows() && rect.y-3>1)
                        {
                            Imgproc.rectangle(finalMat, new Point(rect.x,rect.y-3), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y-3+rect.height+15),new Scalar(255,0,0));
                            crop = gray.submat(rect.y-3, rect.y-3 + rect.height+15, rect.x, rect.x + rect.width);

                        }
                        else {
                            Imgproc.rectangle(finalMat, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(255,0,0));
                            crop = gray.submat(rect.y, rect.y + rect.height, rect.x, rect.x + rect.width);
                        }

                        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(crop.width(), crop.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(crop, bmp);
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, contourIdx+".jpg" , null);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What if you use the blob centroids to order the words from top left corner to right bottom? The first centroid is also the closest to (0,0)...

Comment: I'm not willing to read through uncommented code, but this is actually trivial. you find words of each line through similar y coordinates and then sort those line words by ascending x.